Filtering for unique pairs in a SQL join- simplify a working query
I have data for event registrations where users have an account on the website (user_id), submit a form for registration (nametag), and pay via stripe (order_id).
Each registration must have a unique payment associated with it. Sometimes one person will log in and register themselves and their friends, which trips up the current model.
The below query results in the correct answer. Is there a simpler way to do it?
-- registration form table
with forms as (
  select
    1 as user_id,
    'jeff' as nametag
  union all
  select
    1 as user_id,
    'john' as nametag
  union all
  select
    1 as user_id,
    'jim' as nametag
),

-- paid orders table
orders as (
  select
    1 as user_id,
    'abc' as order_id
  union all
  select
    1 as user_id,
    'def' as order_id
  union all
  select
    1 as user_id,
    'zyx' as order_id
),

-- my query
window1 as (
  select
      forms.*,
      orders.order_id,
      row_number() over (partition by order_id order by orders.order_id, forms.nametag) as row_num1
  from forms
  inner join orders
    on forms.user_id = orders.user_id
)

select * except (row_num1, row_num2)
from (
  select
      *,
      row_number() over (partition by row_num1 order by order_id) as row_num2
  from window1
)
where row_num1 = row_num2


output:



user_id
nametag
order_id




1
jeff
abc


1
jim
def


1
john
xyz




Hi - what’s your definition of “simpler” i.e. what are you actually trying to achieve? Do you want the query to run faster (in which case you need to update your question with the DDL for the tables plus the EXPLAIN PLAN for your query), do you want the code to be shorter (thought I’m not sure why you would care), or something else?

The goal of a simpler query is purely for maintainability when I come back to this later. I'm working solo on this project, and the entire dataset is <50MB.

It would be good for design to have some column to order by like transaction timestamp, and respectively user registration timestamp.
Assuming it's not present the following should simplify your query:
select
    vw_forms.user_id,
    vw_forms.nametag,
    vw_orders.order_id
from 
    (select *, row_number() over (partition by user_id) as r_forms from forms) vw_forms
inner join 
    (select *, row_number() over (partition by user_id) as r_orders from orders) vw_orders
on 
    vw_forms.user_id = vw_orders.user_id and vw_forms.r_forms = vw_orders.r_orders

I skip ordering, because from your description I cannot really discern why would you do it.

Thank you! This is a lot better than what I have.

you can use a combination of ROW_NUMBER() and JOIN without needing to resort to complex window functions or subqueries.
Here’s a simpler approach:
Here’s a simpler approach:

Rank forms and orders independently.
Join the ranked forms and orders on the rankings

 WITH ranked_forms AS (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        nametag,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY nametag) AS form_rank
    FROM forms
),
ranked_orders AS (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        order_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY order_id) AS order_rank
    FROM orders
)
SELECT
    rf.user_id,
    rf.nametag,
    ro.order_id
FROM
    ranked_forms rf
INNER JOIN
    ranked_orders ro
    ON rf.user_id = ro.user_id
    AND rf.form_rank = ro.order_rank; 

The output will match each form to a unique order based on their rank:

user_id | nametag | order_id
--------|---------|---------
1       | jeff    | abc
1       | john    | def
1       | jim     | zyx


